# Real breakpoint with qemu and gdb

Tags: qemu

I am trying to learn malware analysis.

Sometimes, a malware can detect breakpoints and debug mode.
A malware can also be onfuscated.

What i want to do is to setup a virtual computer with qemu and i want to "pause" qemu in order to inspect raw memory.

Do you think this is possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess that you are running a linux kernel so you should :

-compile your kernel with debug info .

-configure qemu with debug info option
`./configure --target-list=your_virtual_target –enable-debug-info

-compile Qemu.

-run qemu

-run your system under GDB with option -S -s  and you can get and Use the x command to examine memory.

Comment: Thanks but how will i pause virtual cpu ?

Comment: you can put a breakpoint where you want to stop or you can just press Ctrl+C

Comment: in fact you need a debug tools or debuging it with gdb to stop the system

Comment: there is also a hardware debug tools that can be used for this purpose